# Azure webJob scheduler error

Tags: azure, scheduler

I have a simple bat file which calls an aspx page. 
I zipped the bat file and uploaded it on azure webjobs. The website is uploaded on azure with database also on azure. the problem is i m not able to use web jobs the error log is below. Please help

```
    [04/02/2014 11:22:51 > 439c50: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
    [04/02/2014 11:22:51 > 439c50: SYS INFO] Run script 'schedularGiveScheduledAwards.bat' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
    [04/02/2014 11:22:51 > 439c50: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
    [04/02/2014 11:22:51 > 439c50: ERR ] The system cannot find the path specified.
    [04/02/2014 11:22:51 > 439c50: INFO] 
    [04/02/2014 11:22:51 > 439c50: INFO] C:\DWASFiles\Sites\testblinkawards\Temp\jobs\triggered\ondemand\qni4mbbd.jj4>"c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://testblinkawards.azurewebsites.net/GiveScheduledAwards.aspx 
    [04/02/2014 11:22:51 > 439c50: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
    [04/02/2014 11:22:51 > 439c50: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
```

Comment: help pls. m new to azure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use **Internet Explorer** in an Azure website.

If you just want to ping the url (or even get the response), you can use `curl`:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

Use **Debug Console** to try out your commands: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/03/04/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about.aspx